# How do I configure a Spring JavaMailSender using a properties file?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

Not (yet) a Spring expert, so maybe my question has a straight answer...
Need to provide some mailing services in my app and wanted to take advantage of Spring to reduce the amount of code I would have to write.
All mail server configuration should remain simple and external, as the application may be installed in any environment.
I could provide an external properties file (using `util:properties` tag) and then fill all `JavaMailSender` properties from there.
The trouble is, there are a lot of mail properties to provide and I'm not sure I'll list all of them, not to mention the trouble when one would have to fill them all...
I was wondering if there is something like `configLocation` property for `VelocityEngineFactoryBean`, which allows loading all specified properties from an external properties file.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do? _I could provide an external properties file (using util:properties tag) and then fill all JavaMailSender properties from there. The trouble is, there are a lot of mail properties to provide_ From that statement, you don't want to use an external property file. Then you say,   _I was wondering if there is something like configLocation property for VelocityEngineFactoryBean, which allows loading all specified properties from an external properties file._ So do you want to use an external file or don't want to use? Or did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Sorry, not clear enough... I do want to use an external properties file, but directly, not by using the properties in that file to specify the mailer configuration options one by one. That's why I gave the Velocity example - all you do in that case is specify the external file and then the Spring class will directly read that file.  `util:properties` only provides access to the file, but requires explicit usage of its contents in the Spring configuration file.